# Change sort order items in a asp.net table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am used to using a controller, but I inherited a bit of code and need to do a (what should be) very simple modification.

the code is straight forward:

```
       <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.DriverDetail.OrderBy(s => s.DriverNumber))
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DriverNumber)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                                </td>
```

I just need to sort it by the field DriverNumber (like it is) but in descending order vs assc.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean `.OrderByDescending(s => s.DriverNumber)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Enumerable.OrderByDescending(...)

Comment: wow....I did not know that existed.
Sorry for the dumb question!